# @"23.0984" USD to @"23.09 USD"

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am sending URLRequest as mentioned below.

```
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil]; 
NSString *balanceString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

And I am getting @"23.0984 USD" in balanceString 
Then I would like to display it on uilabel.tex= 23.09 USD Please help me

Comment: Are you sure you want to "clip" to 23.09, instead of rounding to the nearest 2-digit number, which is 23.10?

Comment: @Daniel oops my mistake I would like to round the digits also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil]; 
NSString *balanceString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
float amount = [balanceString floatValue]; // This will return 23.0984 as a float
NSString *formattedAmount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%01.2f USD", amount];
```

Comment: It's not the cleanest answer. In fact, it's the worst in terms of "clean-ness". But if you're absolutely certain that you'll always receive a string formatted like this, you don't have to go all the way to instanciating a scanner.

Answer (score 1):

There might be easier ways.. But this should work..

```
NSString *originalString = @"23.0984 USD";
NSString *numberString   = [originalString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" USD"
                                                         withString:@""];
float  number   = [numberString floatValue];

NSString *changedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",number];

NSLog(@"ChangedString : %@ USD",changedString);
```

**EDIT:** This answer is already accepted. But I think a better method to get number from string is to **search for spaces** rather than replacing hardcoded string **@" USD"**.

```
NSString *originalString = @"23.0984 USD";
NSString *numberString = nil;
NSArray *parts  =  [originalString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]; //space
if(parts && [parts lenght]){
    numberString = [parts objectAtIndex:0];
}
float number   = [numberString floatValue];

NSString *changedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",number];

NSLog(@"ChangedString : %@ USD",changedString);
```

Comment: this only works responses coming with " USD". If you get strings with other currencies, it is better to use @Daniel answer given below, where it strips out number by checking for white spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Then something like this should work:

```
    NSString * inp = @"29.2994 USD";
    // Initialize a scanner to process the input
    NSScanner * scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:inp];

    // Pull out a floating point value
    float v;
    [scanner scanFloat:&v];

    NSCharacterSet * ws = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
    // scan through the whitespace after the float
    [scanner scanCharactersFromSet:ws intoString:nil];

    NSString * currency;
    [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:ws intoString:&currency];

    // write out value:
    uilabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f %@",v,currency];
```

Comment: Don't use float for currency values. Use an integer based on the smallest unit (e.g. cents).

Comment: @echristopherson - In principle, I agree with you.  However, I do not know of a clean way to properly round what he's looking for without using floating points.  Suggestions?

Comment: Never mind my boneheadedness. I was overlooking the number of fractional digits. I'm guessing a special scanner would have to be created that could return the amount times 10,000; but if there can be more than four fractional digits, I have no clue what to do.

Comment: @echristopherson - if you wanted this to get out of hand, you could pretty easily custom-scanner this - an integer for the dollars, then after the period, you scan two characters, and then you just go down the chain until you rule out the possibility of the digit in the cents place changing (which can roll-over into the dollars amount as well).